# "Er wollte das gesagt haben wollen." - Ist dieser Satz grammatisch richtig?

Tags: modal-verb

Ist der Satz "Er wollte das gesagt haben wollen" grammatisch richtig?
Und ergibt auch die Bedeutung Sinn?

Meiner Ansicht nach gibt es hier keinen Fehler, weil das erste "wollen" sich in besonderer Gebrauchsweise mit dem Perfekt verbindet, und das typische "wollen" dann hinten angeschoben wird.

In der Bedeutung würde ich es so umschreiben:

> Er behauptet, dass er in der Vergangenheit vorhatte, es zu sagen.

Ich sehe hier also kein Problem. Was meint ihr?

Nachtrag:
Das "wollte" soll im Konjunktiv II sein. Die Antwort von HalvarF ist trotzdem hilfreich. In diesem Sinne ist die "Übersetzung" eventuell

> Person 1 sagte, dass Person 2 behauptet, dass er (Person 2) vorhatte, es gesagt zu haben.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vorher kurz: In der "Übersetzung" (ich nenne das mal im Weiteren so) müsste das Hauptverb in der Vergangenheit sein (wie "wollte"):

> Er behauptet**e**, dass er in der Vergangenheit vorhatte, es zu sagen.

Aber stimmt die Übersetzung sonst?

Ich baue mal die Verbstruktur von "Er wollte das gesagt haben wollen" schrittweise auf:

> Ebene 0: Er sagt es.
> Ebene 1: Er hat es gesagt.
> Ebene 2: Er will es gesagt haben.
> Ebene 3: Er wollte es gesagt haben wollen.

Da sieht man in Ebense 2, dass das "Sagen" zeitlich vor dem inneren "Wollen" liegt. Deshalb passt deine Übersetzung für mich nicht ganz. Er hatte nicht in der Vergangenheit vor, es zu sagen, sondern er hatte in der Vergangenheit vor, es gesagt zu haben.

Eine Rückübersetzung der Übersetzung in der Frage wäre:

> Er will das sagen gewollt haben.
> (Oder, auch möglich: Er will das haben sagen wollen.)

Allerdings: Es gibt ja durchaus den Satz:

> Ich will das nur gesagt haben.

Inhaltlich: ich will später darauf verweisen können, dass ich es gesagt habe (und deshalb sage ich es jetzt).

In diesem Sinn verstehe ich auch den Satz in der Frage, und so finde ich ihn auch (mehr oder weniger) sinnvoll:

> Er wollte das gesagt haben wollen.
> = Er behauptete, dass er das gesagt haben wollte.
> = Er behauptete, dass er sicherstellen wollte, das gesagt zu haben.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort. Eine kleine Klarstellung: Das "wollte" in meiner Frage sollte eigentlich im Konjunktiv sein. Aber ändern würde das an der Richtigkeit sowieso nichts, deshalb ist auch deine Antwort hilfreich.

Comment: @323242323242 Dann wäre ja der ganze Satz im Konjunktiv 2, denn "wollte" ist ja das Hauptverb. Bist du sicher? Einen Unterschied macht das aber sonst nicht, die "Übersetzung" "behauptete" kann man ja genauso als Konjunktiv verstehen.

Comment: Oh, stimmt. Wenn es keinen Unterschied macht, außer, dass es eine Redewiedergabe ist, dann ist das gut.